# Why do I get these uncaught type errors when I try initializing a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, initialization, typeerror

Can't figure out these uncaught type errors? I am just trying to use a simple jQuery counter plugin... Other plugins on my site work fine :-/

Errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'counter' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'counter'
```

On my page I have a span like this:

```
<span class="counter counter-analog2" data-direction="up" data-format="23:59:59.9" data-stop="00:00:10.0" data-interval="100">0:00.0</span>
```

I've included the jQuery plugin & css files ABOVE where I initialize them from:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/templates/ja_wall/js/jquery.counter.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/ja_wall/css/jquery.counter-analog2.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Then in my jQuery document ready (which is lower in the code than the plugin include) I initialize the counter plugin like so:

```
$('.main_counter').counter({});
```

I'm totally stuck... maybe its something to do with jQuery needing no-conflict mode? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please do not use caps lock in your post - it just makes us less inclined to answer your question (I edited it out).

Comment: Are you using `noConflict` in your code somewhere?  `.counter` seems to depend on using the `$` for jQuery.  Can you update that plugin's code to use jQuery instead?

Comment: *slaps self on wrist* Sorry!

Comment: I might be able to update that plugins code... I am not totally sure how to do that however? Would you mind explaining further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is another library which is overriding the `$` variable.

The `counter` plugin implementation seems to be having some problem. In jQuery
plugin development it is common practise not to use the `$` variable directly but use `jQuery` variable and use a self executing anonymous function to inject it.

In your case one solution can be to change the following line in the jquery.counter.js

```
!(function (context, definition) {
  if (typeof define == 'function' && typeof define.amd  == 'object') define(['jquery'], definition);
  else definition(context['$']);
}(this, function ($) {
```

to

```
!(function (context, definition) {
  if (typeof define == 'function' && typeof define.amd  == 'object') define(['jquery'], definition);
  else definition(jQuery);
}(this, function ($) {
```

You are using both `jQuery` and `mootools` both uses the `$` variable to access the core engine. Since you have included the mootools library first and jQuery second, jQuery overrides the `$` variable but any call to [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) will reinstate the initial value.

In your case the `k2.noConflict.js` file is calling `var $K2 = jQuery.noConflict();` which replaces the original value of `$` which is `mootools` in your case.

Since you have called `jQuery.noConflict()` the `$` variable will point to mootools, so if you want to access jQuery you need to use the variable `jQuery` or `$K2`.

The normal way of writing a plugin is as

```
(function($){
    $.fn.x=function(){
        ..... 
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks... I changed the $ to jQuery where I initialize the plugin. Is that what you meant? It's still giving me the errors

Comment: Ok... sweet... let me give that a try

Comment: You guys rock!... I really appreciate the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the plugin isn't being initialized properly.

Try putting
`$.noConflict();`
right before you init your plugin?

Comment: I just tried it like this and got the same errors: $.noConflict();
     $('.main_counter').counter({});